# Angular - Recursive nested reactive forms - Validators?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have built a recursive reactive forms for my company based on those explanations : https://dev.to/julianobrasil/writing-nested-recursive-angular-reactive-forms-a-clean-approach-57fk

I'm trying to add some validations to it that I can passed as parameters in a Json file, along the data I want to used.

Here is a simple version of what I have done : https://stackblitz.com/edit/pinchou-nested-recursive-b9q5j1?file=src/app/group-control/group-control.component.ts

The basic structure is like this :

```
{
  groups: [
    {
      variable: null,
      isMandatory: true,
      isEditable: true,
      groups: []
    }
}
```

Groups is a list of group containing the variable to edit and two flags to know if it's editable and mandatory. Each groups can contains a list of groups. (Parent-children)

The '**app.component**' will manage the first group and each children will by manage by group-control (with the validation).

We can see the first one is editable and mandatory on the '***group-control***' component. If a value is changed, it's changed in the '***app***' component as well.

If a value is mandatory, the validation work in the '***condition-form***' component. As we can see, the first one who is mandatory emit a validation error because the field is empty. But the **submit** button on '***app***' component stays enable anyway (based on form validation in '**app-component**').

What can I do to communicate the validations between those components with **NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR** and/or **NG_VALIDATORS** ?

Comment: It'd be nice if your example would be a little more... minimal :) It's hard to see where the validation is happening let alone find the problem you described.

Comment: Hi Mike! I edit and minimize the code the more I can right now and I add a little more information to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And after two days of research, I have find a solution just after posting my question!

I had to change my function 'validate' in 'group-control' to :

```
  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors {
    return this._form.valid ? null : this._form.controls.variable.errors;
  }
```

I was only returning the 'control.errors' but this one haven't received any error yet. I needed to return the one from my specific control I need (controls.variable.errors)